# Ruby on Rails plugin for showing line numbers in log for SQL queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, logging

Does anybody know any plugin, that can show line numbers for SQL queries in Rails logs? Something like this:

```
User Load (0.003154)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) - (user.rb, line 24)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This would be quite difficult.  You can get the current call stack in ruby, but determining which of the stack frames is the one you want in your log would be difficult.  Perhaps the first one that contains RAILS_ROOT/app or RAILS_ROOT/lib would be appropriate.

Comment: Daniel, why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This plugin puts the stack trace in your logs.  As Daniel mentions it would be tricky to determine the line you wanted but I suspect you could work something out, and the trace itself may be good enough.

https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace

Be careful to set it up so you can turn it on and off.  I used this for awhile, and while useful for tracking down specific bugs, it drove me nuts if it was on all the time.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find /projects/querytrace/